# Change the color of jfreechart piechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to change the color of the "pieces" of pie in my jfreechart PieChart3D, this is the code that renders the piechart:

```
<% response.setContentType("image/png"); %><%@page import="org.jfree.data.general.*"%><%@page import="org.jfree.chart.*"%><%@page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.*"%><%@page import="java.awt.Color" %><%

        DefaultPieDataset ds = (DefaultPieDataset)session.getAttribute("usagePieOutputDataset");

  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D
  (
   null,  // Title
   ds,  // Dataset
   false,  // Show legend
   false,  // Use tooltips
   false  // Configure chart to generate URLs?
  );

     chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
     chart.setBorderVisible(false);

  PiePlot3D plot = ( PiePlot3D )chart.getPlot();
  plot.setDepthFactor(0.0);
  plot.setLabelGenerator(null); //null means no labels

  plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  plot.setLabelFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial",  java.awt.Font.BOLD, 10));


  ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), chart, 150, 144);
%>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The color for each section is normally populated from the plot's DrawingSupplier. You can override the defaults, though, by calling

```
PiePlot.setSectionPaint(Comparable key, Paint paint);
```

With, this though, you'll need to set each section manually. If you just want a different set of colors, it looks like you could implement DrawingSupplier.

Comment: How to retrieve `Comparable key` ? Is there a method from the `plotPie` object ? I have tried [`plot.getSectionKey(index)`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html#getSectionKey(int)) but it is protected...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 Color[] colors = {Color.green, Color.red, Color.yellow .. /* size of data set */}; 
 PieRenderer renderer = new PieRenderer(colors); 
 renderer.setColor(plot, ds);
```

and as an inner class:

```
static class PieRenderer 
    { 
        private Color[] color; 

        public PieRenderer(Color[] color) 
        { 
            this.color = color; 
        }        

        public void setColor(PiePlot plot, DefaultPieDataset dataset) 
        { 
            List <Comparable> keys = dataset.getKeys(); 
            int aInt; 

            for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) 
            { 
                aInt = i % this.color.length; 
                plot.setSectionPaint(keys.get(i), this.color[aInt]); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```